# Identifying a WPF Control with White UI Automation using search criteria as an "OR" statement

Tags: c#, wpf, ui-automation, white-framework, microsoft-ui-automation

I'm currently trying to automate the testing of a WPF application, and have several controls where the automationID is determined at run time (currently the problem is a toggle button that has been morphed into a drop down menu, where the text of the toggle button is the selected item)

To solve this I believe I could add all the available selections as search criteria and tell the search function of [TestStack.White](https://github.com/TestStack/White) that I wish to use the [OrSearchCondition](https://github.com/TestStack/White/blob/master/src/TestStack.White/UIItems/Finders/OrSearchCondition.cs) property; however, I am not able to find any documentation of how to use this feature and cannot figure it out by reading through the [source code](https://github.com/TestStack/White/blob/6c61106f2a62686636eb7cace0ee187a02db7295/src/TestStack.White/UIItems/Finders/OrSearchCondition.cs).

Additionally, I have found [one relevant question](https://github.com/TestStack/White/issues/475) to this problem on GitHub, although it remains unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `SearchCriteria(SearchCondition searchCondition)` constructor is marked as private I don't believe their is any means for you to create a `SearchCriteria` using the `OrSearchCondition`. It seems like some helper methods need to be added to `SearchCriteria` for allowing the user create `SearchCriteria` with `OrConditions`.

You can work around this by using `SearchCriteria.All` then using linq to iterate over all the automation elements you get back for the property you are looking for. Although I do recommend using caching if you use this approach to prevent a ton of cross process calls.

Comment: Thank-you for mentioning SearchCriteria.All, I'll try using that when I am able to start working on this project again.

I am curious what you mean by cross process calls though, I've not heard that before and don't see an easy definition when looking it up.

Comment: UIA creates a name pipe for each control you get and then communicates from the client (the UIA code you write) to the server (the application under test). Here is a blog post on it with a helpful diagram https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winuiautomation/2010/12/27/uia-custom-patterns-part-3/. By cross process calls I just meant inter-process communication.